# Rails increment login counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my User model, I have a 'sign_in_count' column which I initially set to 1 when the user is created:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

before_save { self.sign_in_count = 1 }

end
```

This works as when I go to the rails console, I can get back 1:

```
u = User.last
u.sign_in_count
=> 1
```

Then I created a method in my SessionsHelper:

```
def sign_in_count(user)
  user.sign_in_count += 1
end
```

Then I call it my SessionsController like so:

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
     log_in user 
     sign_in_count(user)
.
.
.
end
```

But the sign_in_count never seems to increment. I log in perfectly fine. I get no errors or anything. I inspect the console and the sign_in_count is always 1. Any idea as to what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you inspect `user.sign_in_count` or `sign_in_count(user)`?

Comment: The `.increment` method from Thieu looks awesome. Additionally, could your problem be that you currently don't call `user.save`?

Comment: `user.sign_in_count += 1`  doesn't save it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `increment` method ([detail](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment)) instead of, like this:

```
def sign_in_count(user)
  user.increment!(:sign_in_count)
end
```

And, please change `before_save` callback to `before_create` callback. We just initialize `sign_in_count` only one time when new user is created.

In case of you want to decrease `sign_in_count`, please use `decrement`.